# Microsoft Graph SDK error while attempting to create a new SharePoint list item

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have been trying to create a SharePoint list item via the SDK.
The SDK request is functionally identical to the [C# documentation for this type of request.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example)

```
await client
.Sites[siteId]
.Lists[listId]
.Items
.Request()
.AddAsync(new ListItem
{
    Fields = new FieldValueSet
    {
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "Title", "Test" },
            { "Salary", true },
        }
    }
});
```

I keep getting the following 500 error:

```
    "Error": {
            "code": "generalException",
            "message": "General exception while processing",
            "innererror": {
                "date": "2021-08-23T17:13:20",
                "request-id": "3602eb54-5bde-49ac-abde-16078102746b",
                "client-request-id": "3602eb54-5bde-49ac-abde-16078102746b"
            }
        }
```

However if I preform this request via Postman, the request completes successfully and I see the created list item.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Sites/[siteid]/lists/[listid]/items
SdkVersion: postman-graph/v2.0
Authorization: Bearer [token]
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.3
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 32
Request Body
{ 
    "fields" : {
        "Title" : "Test",
        "Salary" : true
    }
}
```

Is there something I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Capture the outgoing request via Fiddler and compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Despite the dictionary `AdditionalData` field taking a `Dictionary<string, object>`, the SDK only can handle it if the value is a string.

Passing a boolean value was causing an error. I just needed to add `.ToString()' to all of my values and it is working now.